# MMenu Not Opening Menu onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mmenu

I have downloaded the JQuery MMenu. I have followed the instructions and tried several fixes from StackOverflow, but still am not getting it to work. I modified the demo and got it to work, but after I copied the code and css, it still doesn't work. Thanks for your help and replies. (Most of the CSS is not mine. I'm using a W3Layout template for this site.)

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>High Rollers Car Club | Home</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

    <!-- mobile menu -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"   href="dist/core/css/jquery.mmenu.all.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/core/js/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mobilemenu").mmenu();
    }); 
    </script>
    </head>
    <body id="indexPg">
    <!--start header-->
    <div class="h_bg">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="logo">
                         <a href="index.html"><img class="hideOnMobile" src="images/logoHRCC_275x275px.png" alt="" /> </a>
                         <div class="mHeader">
                            <a href="#mobilemenu"><!--<img class="hideOnDesktop mobileStyle" src="images/logoHRCC_275x275px.png" alt="" /> --></a>
                        </div> <!-- End mHeader -->
                    </div> <!-- End Logo -->
                    <div class="spacer"></div>


            <div class="hideOnDesktop">

            <nav id="mobilemenu">
                <ul>
                            <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="garage.html"><span>Garage</span></a></li>
                            <li class="has-sub"><a href="join.html"><span>Connect</span></a>                                                                                        
                            <ul>
                                    <li><a href="eventCalendar.html"><span>Event Calendar</span></a>
                                        <!--<ul>
                                           <li><a href="service.html"><span>Sub Item 1</span></a></li>
                                           <li class="last"><a href="service.html"><span>Sub Item 2</span></a></li>
                                        </ul> -->
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="join.html"><span>Membership</span></a></li>
                                        <!--<ul> 
                                           <li><a href="service.html"><span>Sub Item 1</span></a></li>
                                           <li class="last"><a href="service.html"><span>Sub Item 2</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>-->
                                    <li><a href="join.html"><span>Vendor Registration</span></a>
                                    <li><a href="join.html"><span>Venue Sponsorship</span></a>
                                    <li><a href="join.html"><span>Show Registration</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="eventCalendar.html"><span>Calendar</span></a></li>
                            <li class="last"><a href="contact.html"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
            </nav>
            </div>



              <div class="cssmenu hideOnMobile">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="garage.html"><span>Garage</span></a></li>
                        <li class="has-sub"><a href="join.html"><span>Connect</span></a>                                                                                        
                        <ul>
                                <li><a href="eventCalendar.html"><span>Event Calendar</span></a>
                                    <ul>
                                       <li><a href="service.html"><span>Sub Item 1</span></a></li>
                                       <li class="last"><a href="service.html"><span>Sub Item 2</span></a></li>
                                    </ul> 
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="join.html"><span>Membership</span></a>
                                    <ul> 
                                       <li><a href="service.html"><span>Sub Item 1</span></a></li>
                                       <li class="last"><a href="service.html"><span>Sub Item 2</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                <li><a href="join.html"><span>Vendor Registration</span></a>
                                <li><a href="join.html"><span>Venue Sponsorship</span></a>
                                <li><a href="join.html"><span>Show Registration</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="eventCalendar.html"><span>Calendar</span></a></li>
                        <li class="last"><a href="contact.html"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                <div class="clear"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
 html {
    height: 100%;
    }

    body {
    font-family: Arial, Geneva,Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
    .wrap{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:80%;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
    .wrapper{
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 4%;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 4%;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    position: relative;
}

/*start header */
.h_bg{
    border-bottom: 8px solid #E6E6E6;
    background-color: #161616;
}

.header{
    padding: 2% 0;
    position: relative;
}

.logo{
    float: left;
}

.hideOnDesktop {
    display: none;
}

.spacer {
    background: #161616;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.cssmenu {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    float: right;
}

.cssmenu > ul > li {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background: #f6f6f6; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f6f6f6 1%, #f0f0f0 19%, #efefef 39%, #ededed 59%, #dddddd 98%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#f6f6f6), color-stop(19%,#f0f0f0), color-stop(39%,#efefef), color-stop(59%,#ededed), color-stop(98%,#dddddd)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #f6f6f6 1%,#f0f0f0 19%,#efefef 39%,#ededed 59%,#dddddd 98%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #f6f6f6 1%,#f0f0f0 19%,#efefef 39%,#ededed 59%,#dddddd 98%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #f6f6f6 1%,#f0f0f0 19%,#efefef 39%,#ededed 59%,#dddddd 98%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #f6f6f6 1%,#f0f0f0 19%,#efefef 39%,#ededed 59%,#dddddd 98%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f6f6f6', endColorstr='#dddddd',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.cssmenu > ul > li.active a{
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #9d9d9d; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #9d9d9d 5%, #8d8d8d 40%, #7d7d7d 68%, #6d6d6d 82%, #5d5d5d 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(5%,#9d9d9d), color-stop(40%,#8d8d8d), color-stop(68%,#7d7d7d), color-stop(82%,#6d6d6d), color-stop(100%,#5d5d5d)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #9d9d9d 5%,#8d8d8d 40%,#7d7d7d 68%,#6d6d6d 82%,#5d5d5d 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #9d9d9d 5%,#8d8d8d 40%,#7d7d7d 68%,#6d6d6d 82%,#5d5d5d 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #9d9d9d 5%,#8d8d8d 40%,#7d7d7d 68%,#6d6d6d 82%,#5d5d5d 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #9d9d9d 5%,#8d8d8d 40%,#7d7d7d 68%,#6d6d6d 82%,#5d5d5d 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#9d9d9d', endColorstr='#5d5d5d',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.cssmenu > ul > li span img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Julius Sans One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #161616;
    line-height: 3.8em;
    padding: 14px 24px;
    -webkit-transition: color .15s;
    -moz-transition: color .15s;
    -o-transition: color .15s;
    transition: color .15s;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
    -webkit-transition: 0.9s;
    -moz-transition: 0.9s;
    -o-transition: 0.9s;
    transition: 0.9s;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #9d9d9d; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #9d9d9d 5%, #8d8d8d 40%, #7d7d7d 68%, #6d6d6d 82%, #5d5d5d 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(5%,#9d9d9d), color-stop(40%,#8d8d8d), color-stop(68%,#7d7d7d), color-stop(82%,#6d6d6d), color-stop(100%,#5d5d5d)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #9d9d9d 5%,#8d8d8d 40%,#7d7d7d 68%,#6d6d6d 82%,#5d5d5d 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #9d9d9d 5%,#8d8d8d 40%,#7d7d7d 68%,#6d6d6d 82%,#5d5d5d 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #9d9d9d 5%,#8d8d8d 40%,#7d7d7d 68%,#6d6d6d 82%,#5d5d5d 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #9d9d9d 5%,#8d8d8d 40%,#7d7d7d 68%,#6d6d6d 82%,#5d5d5d 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#9d9d9d', endColorstr='#5d5d5d',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
    font-family: 'Julius Sans One', sans-serif;
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #5C5C5C;
    color:#fff;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 34px;
    margin-left: -90px;
    width: 180px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s .1s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s .1s;
    -o-transition: all .3s .1s;
    transition: all .3s .1s;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 65px;
    visibility: visible;    
}
.cssmenu > ul > li > ul:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border-color: transparent transparent #5C5C5C transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
.cssmenu > ul ul > li {
    position: relative;
}
.cssmenu ul ul a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Julius Sans One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: #5C5C5C;
    padding: 8px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.1s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.1s;
    transition: background-color 0.1s;
}
.cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.cssmenu ul ul ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -16px;
    left: 206px;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    text-align: left;
    width: 160px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}
.cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 190px;
    visibility: visible;
}
.cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
    background: #4F4E4E;
    color: #f0f0f0;
}

.mHeader a {
        background: center center no-repeat transparent;
        background-image: url( data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABkAAAAZCAYAAADE6YVjAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAADhJREFUeNpi/P//PwOtARMDHQBdLGFBYtMq3BiHT3DRPU4YR4NrNAmPJuHRJDyahEeT8Ii3BCDAAF0WBj5Er5idAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC );

        display: block;
        /*width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 10px;
    }
```

Comment: Try moving this to the bottom of the page: `<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mobilemenu").mmenu();
    }); 
    </script>` It could be that your script is kicking in before the html has been created

Comment: Also this looks fishy? `src="dist/core/js/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js"` is that file definitely being called? Usually it would start http or https (or //).

Comment: Yeah I suspect it is the call to the source file that is not working, and as @SamWillis pointed out you should move your mmenu function to the bottom of the page. Fiddle seems to be working: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/1b2jsqsx/

Comment: Thank you both for your quick replies. I moved the script to the bottom of the page, just before the closing body tag. And I pointed jquery.mmenu.min.all.js to one hosted on CloudFlare. However, the menu still does not open. Any other ideas??? This is really driving me crazy!

Comment: @JoeyKango did you get this to work? The best method would be to create a new fiddle, or edit the existing one, then everyone can try and contribute to the code. The other thing you should check: are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Also in connect in my version of the fiddle the menu opens correctly right?

Comment: Yes, I did get this corrected. I actually spelled extensions as 'extentions' and that misspelling caused the script not to work. Thanks for all your help.